# SSIS package deployed to SQLServer not executing packages due to logging provider error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a startup package and within that I call [Execute Package] to run others. So it's like

[Start.dtsx] -> [Execute Pkg 1] -> [Execute Pkg 2] ....

This works fine when I run it under Visual Studio. After I publish to SQL Server under catalogs things doesn't seem to work properly.

Once deployed, I can see all my dtsx files including the start.dtsx. I select the start.dtsx and enter the required parameters (These parameters are set as project level parameters).

Once started and look at the execution reports; it doesn't seem to execute other packages. I see two errors though saying below.

[image]

If I view the context it doesn't give any useful information. Seems like something to do with permissions? However I am logged into my sql server instance as "sa" when running this package. I also noticed that I have a service called "CEIP service for Sql server Integration Services" running under NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY150 Does this have something to do with this? Note that when running in Visual Studio it all works perfectly.

Comment: *"However I am logged into my sql server instance as "sa" when running this package."* Considering that to execute an SSIS package deployed to SSISDB you need to be connected as a Windows User, I find this difficult to believe. Are you, perhaps, actually starting an Agent Job that is running it (which would mean it's running under the AD credentials of the SQL Agent Account, not the `sa` account).

Comment: Tried with windows authentication as well. Still the same. The other thing is I generally have my SQL Agent stopped (set to manual start) in laptop. So, not sure whether SQL Server behind the scenes starts Agent to execute the packages and Agent is not having elevated permissions?

Comment: How are you executing the packages?

Comment: I have deployed to SQL Server from Visual Studio. Then I go to SQL Mgmt Studio -> Go to catalogs -> select the packages, provide parameters and run. it runs but fails with above access denied error

Comment: @user2058413, I don't think it's executing under your account, I might be the database engine or possibly the SSIS server.  However, the best way to go would be to set this up as a SQL agent job - then have it execute under the sqlagent service (configured in the job step) or under a proxy that you would create.  The account it is running under would need to be granted the necessary permissions for whatever the ssis package is doing.

Comment: @user2058413 What is the Log-provider target ? File or Database ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in above comments by @Mark Wojciechowicz in comments, I configured SQL Agent to run the package by creating a step. But I had to change it's account to local system account. The default account didn't had sufficient permissions. Since it's local dev environment I switched to local account and all works fine.